# Running .exe files on different computers.(visual studios)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to run a .exe file which was made with visual studios on a different computer. The computer that i made the program on runs fine but if I run it on a different computers it will not run. I get these errors.

```
   The code execution cannot proceed because ucrtbased.dll was not found. 
   Reinstalling may fix this problem.
```

and...

```
   The code execution cannot proceed because VRUNTIME140D.dll was not found. 
   Reinstalling may fix this problem.
```

Please note I am using C++ to write the code. I downloaded the c++ Redistributable (visual studios 2017) and it still not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Visual Studio runtime (redistributables) for the VS version used to build the application on the machine where you wish to run it.

Comment: But I downloaded that and I am still getting those errors. I followed the steps from this site: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e653a57a-bc32-4134-87bf-df33058f0531/download-microsoft-visual-c-2017-redistributable?forum=vssetup